# White screen while charging when phone is off

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, adb, recovery-mode, bootloader, lenovo-a660

I'm using my phone (Lenovo A660) since more than two years. 
Usually, I do not boot the phone to often (approximately once a month).
However, I recently realized when I turned of the phone, that the battery image is not shown when I charge my phone. 
Instead the screen is completely white.
When I booted the phone again, the screen remained white all the time until I pressed 3 times the power button.
Then my standard launcher (Hola) gets started normally.
However, the screen remains white when I start into bootloader mode or into recovery mode.
Hence, I cannot select anything in a menu (e.g., to perform factory reset or to wipe cache etc...), as I have only a white screen.
May someone has already seen the same behavior and knows where I can search for a solution.
Many thanks in advance for all tips that get posted

**Compact problem description:**

White screen under the following circumstances:

- Charging while phone is off
- normal boot until I press 3 times the power button (has to be done after the phone vibrates shortly)
- booting into recovery mode (either with the keys or with adb command)
- booting into bootloader mode (either with the keys or with adb command)

**Information about the phone:**

- Brand: Lenovo
- List item
- Model: A660
- Android: 4.0.4 Rom: Stock ROM with build number A660_S025_121122
- Recovery image: Stock image or CMW
- Kernel version: 3.0.13 #1 Rooted: Yes with SuperSU v2.01 Fastboot: not supported

**Approaches tried so far:**

- flashed recovery rom with CMW and with stock ROM. No improvement
- Change /system/media/bootanimation.zip and /system/media/images/boot_logo. No improvement
- added and removed again "debug.sf.nobootanimation=1" in the file /system/build.prop. Changes at least that at shutdown an animation is shown or not.
- resetted the /system/fonts folder with a copy of the stock rom
- physically cleaned display contacts according to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bt2kMKLNxVA
- performed a complete dd image of /dev/block/mmcblk0 in order to be able to restore all partitons if something goes wrong
- so far I spent approximately 2 days googling for related problems. However, may someone can provide a key word that I was missing in my search

What I could further provide, if necessary, are for example the logcat, output if that would help to debug the problem or to point me in the right direction.

Once again many thanks for any comment and suggestion.

Comment: As you've got ADB etc. available and already explicitly mentioned factory-reset and cache-wipe: Are you aware you can do that using [`fastboot`](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info) commands? `fastboot erase cache` would clean your cache partition, `fastboot -w erase cache` would be a factory-reset.